# Reading a .csv file (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, io

I see this question and similar questions already but my problem is that it was working fine until a moment ago. Where did I go wrong?
This is a small example I made to work out how to read a .csv file and to pass the values in it to something else, before implementing it in a larger application.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = "data.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        inputStream.next();//Ignore first line
        while(inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = inputStream.next();//gets a whole line
            //create a string array where value at 0 is the name, value at 1 is the quantity, and value at 2 is the price
            String[] values = data.split(",");
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
            System.out.println(values[0] + "\n" + quantity + "\n" + values[2]);
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

I went to do this for my larger program and it gave me the page not found error and when I went to double check this project, it would not run either. It gives me the same error. I restarted Eclipse and checked a few times to find if I accidentally left something out or changed something. `data.csv` is right there in my src folder. I even dagged it over to make it show up in the Eclipse project view. What am I missing?

`Name,Quantity,Price
Tea,100,2.50
Coke,50,2.50
Lays,32,1.00
Cheetos,34,1.10
Snickers,30,1.25
Butterfinger,70,1.50
Five,40,0.75
Orbits,50,0.90`

Comment: What is your working directory when running the code and is the csv file included there?

Comment: A small tip: the `file` may refer to a different path than you are assuming. In order to know what it exactly points to add a `System.out.println(file.toAbsolutePath());` to see which file it is trying to read.

Comment: Path path = Paths.get("yourPath//fileName");  System.out.println(Files.exits(path)); first you check your path is correct or not

Comment: put your cvs file in current work directory  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is limited to the easiest, most powerful way of using opencsv to allow you to hit the ground running.

For reading, create a bean to harbor the information you want to read, annotate the bean fields with the opencsv annotations, then do this:

```
List<MyBean> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(FileReader("yourfile.csv"))
   .withType(Visitors.class).build().parse();
```

For writing, create a bean to harbor the information you want to write, annotate the bean fields with the opencsv annotations, then do this:

```
// List<MyBean> beans comes from somewhere earlier in your code.
 Writer writer = new FileWriter("yourfile.csv");
 StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder beanToCsv = StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).build();
 beanToCsv.write(beans);
 writer.close();
```

Say you're using a tab for your separator, you can do something like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), '\t');
```

or for reading with annotations:

```
CsvToBean csvToBean = CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"))
       .withSeparator('\t').build();
```

And if you single-quoted your escaped characters rather than double-quoting them, you can use the three-argument constructor:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), '\t', '\'');
```

or for reading with annotations:

```
CsvToBean csvToBean = CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"))
       .withSeparator('\t').withQuoteChar('\'').build();
```

At the most basic, you can use opencsv to parse an input and return a String[], thus:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
     String [] nextLine;
     while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
     }
```

Comment: Why did you delete your old post and post basically the same content again (only formatted the correct way) instead of simply editing the old answer?

Comment: I've never heard of a bean before in Java. I'm still pretty new to java. That's some interesting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure why `"data.csv"` stopped working but, I changed the path to `"src/data.csv"` and it works fine. Which begs the question, why did it work one moment and not the next?